# Cross-compiling QtDeclarative for raspberry pi

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, qml, cross-compiling, qtdeclarative

I'm trying to cross compile `qml` for Raspberry pi 3 on a x64 Ubuntu.
I followed this tutorial
https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS, installed Qt 5.6.3 and managed to run QtWidgets applications pretty easily and I'm now looking to use QML.

From what I understood, I need to install `qtjsbackend` and `qtdeclarative` for it to work so I cloned the github repositories and installed `qtjsbackend` without any trouble.
now, when I tried to run `qmake` on `qtdeclarative`, I got some weird errors:
`/home/myname/raspi/qtdeclarative/src/src.pro:13: 'qtConfig' is not a recognized test function.`
It keeps going on until:
`Reading /home/myname/raspi/qtdeclarative/tests/auto/qml/debugger/qdebugmessageservice/qdebugmessageservice.pro
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: qmldebug-private`

I can't find anything on the internet about this, does anyone have an idea of what to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `qtjsbackend` requirement is old, and only needed for Qt 5.1. Newer qtdeclarative no longer use v8 as a JavaScript engine.

The error you are getting there is caused by a mismatch of version dependencies. You are trying to build a qtdeclarative that looks like it is from either a 5.8/5.9 or dev branch against a qtbase that you say is 5.6. If you have Qt 5.6, you want to build the same major & minor version for qtdeclarative, i.e. 5.6 (or a 5.6.x release)

I would suggest that you either use `qt5.git` to get you all the dependencies of the version that you need, or use the tarball releases which contain everything in one "blob".

Alternatively, you should be able to install it from your distribution. I would expect that it is already packaged there, though it may not be the newest version possible.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem and tried following

***Try checking out 5.7 branch from your git repo for qtdeclarative***,

git checkout 5.7
then qmake, make and make install.

Hope this helps.

Cheers